# Truncate unicode string to max bytes

Tags: swift, string, swift3, substring

I need to truncate a (possibly large) unicode string to a max size in bytes. Converting to UTF-16 and then back appears unreliable.

For example:

```
let flags = ""
let result = String(flags.utf16.prefix(3))
```

In this case result is nil.

I need an efficient way to perform this truncation. Ideas?

Comment: You need 8 not 3

Answer (score 0):

String in Swift goes by `UnicodeScalar` and each scalar can take multiple bytes to store. If you just take the first `n` bytes no matter what, chances are that these bytes will not form a correct substring in any encoding when you convert them back.

Now if you change the definition to "take up to the first `n` bytes that can form a valid substring", you can use the `UTF8View`:

```
extension String {
    func firstBytes(_ count: Int) -> UTF8View {
        guard count > 0 else { return self.utf8.prefix(0) }

        var actualByteCount = count
        while actualByteCount > 0 {
            let subview = self.utf8.prefix(actualByteCount)
            if let _ = String(subview) {
                return subview
            } else {
                actualByteCount -= 1
            }
        }

        return self.utf8.prefix(0)
    }
}

let flags = "welcome to  and "

let bytes1 = flags.firstBytes(11)

// the Puerto Rico flag character take 8 bytes to store
// so the actual number of bytes returned is 11, same as bytes1
let bytes2 = flags.firstBytes(13)

// now you can cover the string up to the Puerto Rico flag 
let bytes3 = flags.firstBytes(19)

print("'\(bytes1)'")
print("'\(bytes2)'")
print("'\(bytes3)'")
```

Comment: This is really close, however I'm noticing an issue:

print(String("welcome to  and ".firstBytes(10))!.lengthOfBytes(using: .unicode))
Output:

20

Comment: Unicode scalar is 21-bit but Swift may do some magic behind the scene to store it as UTF-16 (which is what `NSString` uses internally). if  you want the fewest number of bytes that can represent a string, use UTF-8

Comment: Yeah each unicode scalar is a minimum of 2 bytes, while the latin characters are 1 byte in utf8. So this will truncate a utf8 string to a set # of bytes. However the storage encoding is not up to me in this case, I need to truncate a unicode string to a max # of bytes.

Comment: If your storage is a database, I suspect there's already a mechanism to handle string truncation. Unicode is not an encoding, it's a Swift's term. What does the receiving end use, UTF-16 or UTF-8?